# BASH rearrange date in file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
A345435;3/12/2016
D564565;12/29/2017
...
```

Im trying to get the file to this:

```
A345435;20160312
D564565;20171229
...
```

I tried AWK but I get the first part ok and the date is always the same.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {"date -d"$2" +%Y%m%d" | getline newDate; close(newDate); print $1,newDate}'

A345435;20160312
D564565;20160312
...
```

Is not really necessary the use of AWK but what I want to avoid is looping the file for it has ~20k lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$ awk -F'[;/]' '{printf "%s;%s%02d%02d\n",$1,$4,$2,$3}' file
A345435;20160312
D564565;20171229
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just rearranging the existing strings; you don't have to convert via date functions or external programs

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}
  {split($2, mdy, "/");
   print $1, sprintf("%4d%02d%02d", mdy[3], mdy[1], mdy[2]);
  }' datafile
```

Split onto several lines for readability -- you can put on one line if you like

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! I had tried splitting but didn't quite succeed in the adding a zero part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `awk`, but it can be done (messily) in `sed`

```
sed -e 's@;\([[:digit:]]\)/@;0\1/@' -e 's@/\([[:digit:]]\)/@/0\1/@' \
-e 's@;\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\([[:digit:]]\+\)@;\3\1\2@' yourfile
```

The first expression takes any single days and prepends them with a 0, the second does the same for months, and the third expression takes the three numbers day, month, and year, and formats them as desired. I used the '@' sign instead of the normal '/' as the separators for the `sed` commands, since '/' appears in the patterns that need matching.

Comment: This leaves the day part with one digit only. But I managed to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: I just fixed the expression so it works in all cases. It basically works the same way as Aidan's answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, although there's probably a better way to do it.

```
sed -E 's/;([0-9])\//;0\1\//;s/\/([0-9])\//\/0\1\//;s/([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)/\3\1\2/g' your_file > new_file
```

It performs three regex replacements: the first finds single-digit months and prepends a 0, the second finds single-digit days and prepends a 0, and then the third does the conversion between mm-dd-yyyy to yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `bash` and `date` without `awk`.  The arguments to the `date` utility are not well-standardized, so we have alternative code paths for Linux vs. non-Linux (such as BSD variants like Mac).

### test_bash_date

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=';' read -ra line; do
    line_id=${line[0]}
    if [[ $(uname -s) == Linux ]]; then
        line_date=$(date -d "${line[1]}" +%Y%m%d)
    else
        line_date=$(date -j -f %m/%d/%Y "${line[1]}" +%Y%m%d)
    fi
    echo "$line_id;$line_date"
done < test_file
```

### test_file

```
A345435;3/12/2016
D564565;12/29/2017
```

### Output

```
> bash test_bash_date 
A345435;20160312
D564565;20171229
```